# Login & User Account Functionality on Pure Html Based Website

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a piece of e-commerce software that is purely Html based. I want to create the functionality of logging in and having an account.

I can't use PHP or mysql due to .html not being able to process it. I can't change them to .php as the software wouldn't function correctly.

Is there any other way around this? How is it possible to have this functionality and also is it even possible?

Is there a way to make php sit over the top of the html controlling the log in feature somehow?

My host has Php and mysql installed, but I simply cant use it with my webpages

Comment: I think the only correct answer to this is no.

Comment: So your saying it is Impossible?

Comment: You can setup apache to parse .html through the php engine

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible but let's say you would want to do it with JavaScript. JavaScript is client side and is there for insecure. It can be turned off where PHP is server side and so much more secure. The only way to do this is with JavaScript cookies but then the question is where are the password and username stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by telling Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files. This will allow you to add php to your .html files to build a login and user account system effectively over the top of your existing site.

To do this you need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

Then simply add the php tags to you .html pages with the desired php code.

```
<?php
// your php code
?>
```

Comment: Wow... This will my life so much easier. Thanks for the answer